# Simple SSH test Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh, controller

I am simply trying to list the directories after I ssh into a remote machine in my rails app but I am not getting the desired output, what is am I overlooking? The host is an IP.

controller-

```
def index
  @ssh_test = Net::SSH.start( :host =>'xx.x.xx.xx',:user => 'name', :password => 'secret' ) do |ssh|
   result = ssh.exec!('ls')
   puts result
  end
end
```

gemfile-

```
gem 'net-ssh'
```

view

```
<h2><%= @ssh_test %></h2>
```

Shouldn't the current directories directories print to my view? Thanks for your attention.

*UPDATE*

Here is updated progress, still don't seem to fully grasp this.

```
before_filter :set_ssh, :only => [:index]


  def index
    @ssh_dir = Net::SSH.start( @host, @user, :password => @password ) do |ssh|
    result = ssh.exec!('ls')
  end

  def set_ssh
    @host = 'xx.x.xx.xx'
    @user = 'user'
    @password = 'password'
  end
```

view-

```
<h1><%= @ssh_dir( host, user, password).inspect %></h1>
```

Comment: Can you just try the answer I submitted below without your edits above? The second version as I don't think that  Net::SSH.start( :host =>'xx.x.xx.xx',:user => 'name', :password => 'secret' ) is actually a valid call to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the result and the way you're calling start is incorrect, try this:

```
def index
  @ssh_test = Net::SSH.start('xx.x.xx.xx','name', :password => 'secret' ) do |ssh|
   result = ssh.exec!('ls')
   result
  end
end
```

This is the correct way to call start in version 2 of net-ssh according to: http://net-ssh.github.com/net-ssh/

EDIT: Answering where to put your config.

If the ssh server you're going to use is fixed for all environments then I'd probably just put it in an initializer:

```
config/initializers/my_ssh_config.rb
```

which would have:

```
$SSH_HOST = 'xx.x.xx.xx'
$SSH_USERNAME = 'name'
$SSH_PASSWORD = 'secret'
```

Note, personally I would not store the username and password in the config, but maybe try that first just to get it working. (I'd generally make this an env var and do this $SSH_PASSWORD = ENV['SSH_PASSWORD'] etc)

Then your controller action would look like:

def index
      @ssh_test = Net::SSH.start($SSH_HOST, $SSH_USERNAME, :password => $SSH_PASSWORD) do |ssh|
       result = ssh.exec!('ls')
       result
      end
    end

You could also add this to your environment files (e.g. test.rb, development.rb).

Comment: I'm using the version you linked to but I used the above syntax because I wasn't sure where to put those variables? Where would be best practice to put these, in the config directory? And also, doesn't ruby return the last line by default anyway, so I can just have result= ssh.exec('ls') by iteself?

Comment: Yes, you should simply leave it as ssh.exec('ls').

Comment: I ran what you wrote in the 2nd version of your answer in the console and it worked as I expected. I guess my misunderstanding is how to correctly render this in the view.. which is of course a different issue for me. Now I'm currently looking into running a sudo cmd and entering the pass again. Thanks for your help on this.